# Raspberry WiFi hotspot, no ethernet

Tags: pi-3, wifi, hotspot

There is a ton of tutorials on how to make your Pi a hotspot router, but all of them are using ethernet as the "income". What I would like to achieve is to connect to WiFi with my USB WiFi adapter and share the Internet via a hotspot using the Raspberry Pi internal WiFi adapter (or if the signal of the internal WiFi will be slow, I can plug in another WiFi dongle for broadcasting). I tried to follow and adapt [this tutorial](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/) for my purpose, but I guess I'm just too noob :). If anyone could point to similar tutorial or have any idea how to achieve this I would be very thankful.

Comment: It is difficult to help you as you have provided to less detail. You said you tried to adapt a tutorial but don't tell us what you changed from the tutorial. So please change you question and add the relevant parts of the tutorial and what you changed.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at [this tutorial](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-repeater-optional-with-bridge)

It is quite detailled

I succeeded with it but i have found 2 problems (1 is solved).
You can see [my question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90724/how-to-setup-hostapd-to-send-dns-server-address-during-dhcp-session-start-on-rpi) about them

Comment: Linked resources are not guaranteed permanent.  At least outline/summarise the solution to provide a rounded complete answer.